# pdf files are not moved in folders: cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null - ForEach-Object cmdlet vs. foreach loops

Tags: loops, powershell, syntax

I use a script that create folders extracting years from text file (.txt).
 I have some pdf files in **C:\Path** like so

```
Ben - Hur.pdf
Ben 10 - Corsa contro il tempo.pdf
Ben Hur - Dvd2.pdf
Ben-Hur - Dvd1.pdf
Bolide Rosso - Johnny Dark (1954).pdf
Hard Night (Permanent Midnight).pdf
The Dark Valley.pdf
```

Instead file text (`Text4.txt`) is something this

```
Hard Night (Permanent Midnight 1998)
Ben-Hur (1925) 
Ben Hur (1959) [Storico [CURA] 
Ben Hur Dvd2 (1959) 
Ben Hur - Dvd1 (1959)[Top 250 - Ita Eng]
The Dark Valley (2014) [ - Ita Deu Aac] Western
Bolide Rosso - Johnny Dark (1954) [it] Azione
Ben - Hur (1959)
```

Script *extract* years from Text4.txt and make this folder like this

```
1925
1950
1998
```

But when it should move pdf files powershell script returns me this error

> Move.Iten: cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeAm9.png)

This error is strange (I use Powershell 5). Script create correctly folders but not moving files inside. Script is this

```
$movies = @()
(get-content C:\Path\Test4.txt) | foreach($_){
$properties = @{
date = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1,4)
name = $_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf("("))
}
write-host $date
write-host $name

$movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}

$torrentFiles = dir $torrentPath

foreach($movie in $movies){
$datePath = "C:\Path\$($movie.date)"
if(-not(test-path $datePath)) {
new-item $datePath -ItemType "directory"
}
$words = ($movie.name -split '\s') | ?{ $_.Length -gt 1}
$significant = $words.Count
 foreach($torrentFile in $torrentFiles){
 $matchingWords = 0
  foreach($word in $words){
   if($torrentFile.BaseName -match $word){
    $matchingWords += 1
   }
  }
  if($matchingWords -ge $significant){
  $_ | Move-Item -Destination $datePath
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong but wouldn't the first line in Text4.txt return date `Perm`? I'd prefer a RegEx instead of substring to match the proper name/dates.

Comment: mmm, yes I have also `Perm` folder, you can remove text after `(DATE)`using an editor or a regex

Comment: It's your environment,  I deduced that from your data and code with the substring after the opening parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using a `Foreach` loop but then trying to access a property using a pipeline object as you would in a `Foreach-Object` loop.  you need to change `$_` to something that has an actual value, I'm guessing `$torrentFile`

```
if($matchingWords -ge $significant){
  Move-Item -path $torrentfile -Destination $datePath
}
```

Comment: *it works!* But help me to understand: error it was pipeline object used like foreach object loop because `$_` it was undefinited ? For this reason, rather than define an *object as a value* that remained defined as a variable (loop)?

Comment: so `$_` only has a value when you are passing an object through the pipeline, when you use a foreach loop the way you are there is no object in the pipeline so `$_` is null.  That make more sense?

Comment: better, thanks. So my code implementation it returned an *empty* object so `$_` remained valued as a return to the same variable  `$_` so it was null. This explanation is correct ?

Comment: not exactly, `$_` only has meaning in a pipeline, since you were using it outside of a pipeline it will always be null.

Comment: mmm.. ok..but `null` what is exactly for Powershell ? an error ? a function ? So, if in my wrong code implementation I set *$_* like null how powershell understand this and return me an object-loop to avoid execute instruction ? Depends by method implemented in powershell *source code* kernel or in general `null` is a return function like loop ?

Comment: `null` in Powershell is the same as `null` in any other language, it literally means "nothing" or "no value".Apologies but I'm not quite sure what you're  asking beyond that, the basic problem you are encountering is that `$_` only available when you are using a `Foreach-Object` loop(see mklement0's awesome explanation of this)

Comment: Thanks Mike, now is more clear for me: `no value`. This is useful because in some scripts I need to have this situation :)

Answer (score 1):

To *complement* [Mike Garuccio's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41188761/45375) with some **background information**:

- `ForEach-Object` is a ***cmdlet*** that you **use in a *pipeline*** to *iteratively process input*, with each input object represented as **automatic variable `$_` or `$PSItem`**. You can think of it as an ***implicit loop***.
- `foreach` is a ***language keyword*** that initiates a **flow-control *statement*** for writing ***explicit* loops in a script**; you ***choose* the name of the iteration variable** as well as the collection to loop over, such as `$movie` in
  `foreach ($move in $movies) { ... }`.

  - You cannot (directly) use a `foreach` *statement* in a pipeline.
  - `$_` has no meaning inside a `foreach` loop.

The two are distinct, and used in different situations; unfortunately, the fact **that PowerShell provides an *alias* for `ForEach-Object` cmdlet also named `foreach` is somewhat confusing**.

If you use `foreach`, PowerShell knows from the parsing context whether you're referring to the cmdlet or the language keyword - see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).

Cmdlets are parsed in so-called *argument mode*, which is, loosely speaking, command-line syntax: a command name followed by whitespace-separated arguments. (The other mode, which works like in a traditional programming language, is *expression mode*).

---

Note that your attempt to use `... | foreach($_){ ... }` actually called the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, via its `foreach` alias - even though the - extraneous - `($_)` part happened to make it *look* like the `foreach` *statement*.

Again: `$_` is *automatically* set to the pipeline object at hand - no need to declare an iterator variable.

The `($_)` part of your command was effectively *quietly ignored*
(in effect, it ultimately bound `$null` - because `$_` has no value at that point, outside of a script block - to the `-Begin` script block, which is a no-op).

Comment: Thank you mklement0. I need to understand better `null` - what is exactly null for Powershell ? an error ? a function ? A loop ? So, if in my wrong code implementation I set *$_* like null how powershell understand this and return me an object-loop to avoid execute instruction ? Depends by method implemented in powershell *source code* or by O.S kernel or in general `null` is a return function like loop ?

Comment: Thank you for posting this!  much better explanation of the concepts involved than I had posted.

Comment: @JackyNed: I don't fully understand your questions, but let me say this: `$null` is a special value that usually denotes the absence of data. Many PowerShell cmdlets treat an attempt to pass `$null` as an argument as an error, as happened to you with `Move-Item` (because a string containing a path to an existing filesystem item is needed).