# Make folder structure for files spitting strings in file txt using foreach loops

Tags: loops, powershell, syntax

I have these files

```
Irrational Man.pdf
Il Ponte Delle Spie (2015).pdf
Interiors.pdf
Le Ragazze della Terra Sono Facili.pdf
Star Wars Il Risveglio Della Forza.pdf
```

My script (look below) make this situation:
[image: script that I use]

but I should to order files also by genre inside each year folder like so:
[image: script that I expect]

Strings inside Text4.txt is so formatted

```
Irrational Man (2015) #Commedy#
Il Ponte Delle Spie (2015) #Thriller#
Interiors (1978) #dramatic#
Le Ragazze della Terra Sono Facili (1989) #adventure, comedy#
Star Wars Il Risveglio Della Forza (2015) #science fiction, adventure, comedy#
```

For each files moved inside year folders like

```
1978
1989
2015
```

I need to order each files inside *by genre* also that I find in Text4.txt

This is the folder structure that I expected (files are only with .pdf extensions)

```
1978
  |__dramatic
  |      |_Interiors.pdf

1989
  |__adventure, comedy
  |    |_Le Ragazze della Terra Sono Facili.pdf

2015
  |__comedy
  |    |_Irrational Man.pdf
  |
  |__ science fiction, adventure, comedy
  |                |_Star Wars Il Risveglio Della Forza.pdf
  |
  |__ thriller
         |_Il Ponte Delle Spie (2015).pdf
         |_xxxx.pdf
```

This is code that I use

```
$movies = @()
(get-content C:\Path\Test4.txt) | foreach($_){
$properties = @{
date = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1,4)
name = $_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf("("))
}
write-host $date
write-host $name

$movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}

$torrentFiles = dir $torrentPath

foreach($movie in $movies){
$datePath = "C:\Path\$($movie.date)"
if(-not(test-path $datePath)) {
new-item $datePath -ItemType "directory"
}
$words = ($movie.name -split '\s') | ?{ $_.Length -gt 1}
$significant = $words.Count
 foreach($torrentFile in $torrentFiles){
 $matchingWords = 0
  foreach($word in $words){
   if($torrentFile.BaseName -match $word){
    $matchingWords += 1
   }
  }
  if($matchingWords -ge $significant){
  Move-Item -path $torrentfile -Destination $datePath
 }
 }
}
```

I try to add genre variable with regex to delimitate position of string to make the correctly folders

```
$properties = @{
date = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1,4)
name = $_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf("("))
genre = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("#")$"#")
}
write-host $date
write-host $name
write-host $genre
```

But I can't understand how implement genre variable inside this piece of code

```
$words = ($movie.name -split '\s') | ?{ $_.Length -gt 1}
$significant = $words.Count
 foreach($torrentFile in $torrentFiles){
 $matchingWords = 0
  foreach($word in $words){
   if($torrentFile.BaseName -match $word){
    $matchingWords += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** completed the script, but can't test the $torrentfiles/part Especially the word count.
Please change the vars $File $Base and $torrentpath to fit your needs.

```cs
#SortTo-Folders.ps1
$File = ".\Text4.txt"
$Base = "C:\Path\"
$torrentPath = "."
$movies = @()

## Evaluate RegEx https://www.regex101.com/r/F24BfH/1
$RegEx = '^(?<Name>[^\(]+)\(.*?(?<Date>\d+)\).#(?<Genre>[^#]+)#.*$'
(get-content $File ) | foreach{
    If ($_ -match $RegEx){
        $properties = @{
            date = $matches.Date
            name = $matches.Name
            genre = $matches.Genre 
        }
        $movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
    }
}
$movies
#--------------------------------------------------------------

$torrentFiles = Dir $torrentPath

foreach($movie in $movies){
    $DateGenrePath = "$Base$($movie.date)\$($movie.genre)"
    if(!(test-path $DateGenrePath)) {
        new-item $DateGenrePath -ItemType "directory"
    }
    $words = ($movie.name -split '\s') | ?{ $_.Length -gt 1}
    $significant = $words.Count
    foreach($torrentFile in $torrentFiles){
        $matchingWords = 0
        foreach($word in $words){
            if($torrentFile.BaseName -match $word){
                $matchingWords += 1
            }
        }
        if($matchingWords -ge $significant){
            Move-Item -Path $torrentFile -Destination $DateGenrePath -whatif
        }
    }
}
```

To see the RegEx working, visit https://www.regex101.com/r/F24BfH/1

Comment: @Jacky Ned completed my script and tested as much as possible without having your environment. Just give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, your script works and create folders correctly also folders with multiple words like `science fiction, adventure, comedy` but.. **files are not moved inside!** Why ? I test with simple environment, test please: https://www.dropbox.com/s/itdapiganhb0ape/Path.rar

Comment: You did think off to remove the -whatif ? This is a "seatbelt" to show you what happens when ...

Comment: @LotPings If you would explain how your code works and mentioned things like `whatif` it is usually prefered to just a wall of code saying "Try it"

Comment: @Matt I would agree, but this has a [history in another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188638/)  where I recommended using a RegEx for the matching. I had already coded most of it but he seemed ok with explanantions from MikeGarrucio and mklement. Code differences to his own are not that great. For the RegEx the link provided should help.

Comment: @LotPings Your regex works matching text strings, but don't move if pdf/torrent filenames is not similar or identical among filenames and string name inside txt. Maybe I need a better regex in future to move also that files. Thanks anyway, this is a good solution

Comment: @JackyNed I think it's the matching word algorythm. $matchingwords can never be greater than $significant so -ge isn't a good choice. IMO `if($matchingWords -ge $significant-1)' should be ok if $matchingWords -ge 2

Answer (score 1):

my solution

```
$dirwithfile="c:\temp\test"
$Newdirfile="C:\temp\test2"

#template for describe your datas
$template=@"
{Title*:Word1 word2} ({Year:1234}) #{Categories:Category1}#
{Title*:Word3} ({Year:4567}) #{Categories:Category2, Category1, Category3}#
{Title*:Word5 Word6} ({Year:1956}) #{Categories:Category1 Category2, Category3, Category4}#
"@

#cut datas and build list with all necessery data
$listdata=gc C:\temp\text4.txt | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | %{ 
[pscustomobject]@{
                    Title=$_.Title;
                    Year=$_.Year;
                    Categorie=$_.Categories; 
                    PathBefore="$dirwithfile\$($_.Title).pdf";
                    PathAfter="$Newdirfile\$($_.Year)\$($_.Categories)"
                 }
}

$listdata | %{New-Item -ItemType Directory $_.PathAfter -Force;  Move-Item $_.PathBefore $_.PathAfter -Force }
```

Comment: Thanks Esperento, I test your script but strings with multiple words separated by `,` generate only folders with a single word like `adventure` so if I have `#adventure, comedy#` your script generate 2 folders and not one folder that I expect. This cause also empty folder situation because a string like *Le Ragazze della Terra Sono Facili (1989) #adventure, comedy#* can't be splitted in 2 genres because I consider  *#adventure, comedy#* like a `multiple words = single genre = one folder` so I expect folder called `adventure, comedy` . Look your works http://i.imgur.com/0gbrs6z.png

Comment: if you have #adventure, comedy# you want just a copy in adventure?

Comment: no, it should copy in a folder called `adventure, comedy` not in a folder called 'adventure' because genre is composed with multiple word. However I save also your solution, may be useful

Comment: It works good but don't move files inside..mmm.. you missing something ?, only create folder structure. However I test your script for many files and seems your template solution works better. Try my environment `https://www.dropbox.com/s/grdzgob7d9ko9p4/temp - moving files solution.rar`

Comment: it work on my dirs its Strange, have you PowerShell v5?

Comment: except "Il Ponte Delle Spie (2015).pdf" which have (2015) in his name, other files are moved

Comment: yes, I used Powershell 5 - you have try with my environment, maybe depends about Text4 ? Maybe some illegal character in strings like `:`freeze moving inside. For example *Star Wars:the awaken..*

Comment: i have try your environment but your problem is: you have file .torrent and not .pdf (--> modify my code for PathBefore="$dirwithfile\$($_.Title).torrent") , the files names in C:\temp\text4.txt are not equals to files name in your dir

Comment: No, not depends about illegal character, I check and remove also empty strings without text inside # and also remove that lines but nothing change: folder structure is created but no moving inside. I using Win 2012 server, PS version is 5.0.10586.117

Comment: my script doesnt work because "Uomini e Donne - Istruzioni per l'uso (1996)" is différent of "Uomini_e_Donne___Istruzioni_per_l_uso__96"

Comment: I change file name and your line `$listdata | %{New-Item -ItemType Directory $_.PathAfter -Force;  Move-Item $_.PathBefore $_.PathAfter -Force }` into `$listdata | %{New-Item -ItemType Directory $_.PathAfter -Force;  Move-Item $_.PathBefore="$dirwithfile\$($_.Title).torrent" $_.PathAfter -Force }` but nothing change

Comment: Yes, I see now the difference between file torrent and strings name inside txt file. But why your script don't move even a file? There are the same names among the filesnames and strings inside txt. LotPing solution move files but no if name aren't identical, maybe I need a better regex ?. Sometimes I have duplicates because there a different version of same video. Thanks for tips Esperanto

Comment: My solution compare files names directly, solution of Lotping compare word of file name. For Lotping "bella vita" and "vita bella" is the same movie...

Comment: ok, your solution is good for arxiv pdf files that have same names both filenames and strings :). But is correct my edit code above to allow .torrent files or I am missing some simbol ? Is correct this edit ? `$listdata | %{New-Item -ItemType Directory $_.PathAfter -Force; Move-Item $_.PathBefore="$dirwithfile\$($_.Title).torrent") $_.PathAfter -Force }`